# I cant ping the local network but i can ping the internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, ping

Hi I recently flashed a fresh version of raspbian onto my pi 3 but I'm running into a strange problem where I cant ping any other machines on my lan other than the router. I am able to ping outside addresses just not local machines.

I am able to ping my pi from my windows 10 machine but not the other way around. I have tried disabling the firewall on my windows machine but that did not work. I have also enabled ICMP reply on the windows machine but that did not work either. I am able to post any further information you may need

I have disabled the firewall on the windows machine and I am able to ping 8.8.8.8 but when I ping the local machine i get Destination Host Unreachable. I am using a Linksys e3000 if that helps at all.

Comment: What IP address and subnet is on each machine, and are they static or assigned by DHCP?

Comment: IP for the windows machine is 192.168.1.106
Ip for pi is 192.168.1.131 both with the subnet mask 255.255.255.0

Comment: The first thing I'd do in this situation is get Wireshark running on each machine and if you can see ICMP packets entering and leaving the network interfaces. EDIT. Is the router the common point between them? I'd look there.

Comment: Ok let me get that set up and ill report back

Comment: Can you ping the windows machine from the window machine?

Comment: Usually in there cases ping is not running on the remote machine, or is blocked by its firewall. Why not just try to connect to a real service (one that you want to use).

Comment: Are you asking if i can ping the loopback address?

Comment: You say "I cant ping any other machines on my lan"; so aside from the single Windows 10 machine you then mention, have you actually also tested it with other computers on the LAN, or just that one Windows 10 machine and your router?

Comment: I have tried it with other machines other then the router also running windows 10. 

@richard 176 192.279970000 Raspberr_a8:4b:d4 Broadcast ARP 42 Who has 192.168.1.106?  Tell 192.168.1.131

this is what im getting when i listen on my interface on the pi

Comment: Is the Pi connecting to the E3000 via Wi-Fi, or via Ethernet? If Wi-Fi, does the same problem happen when you connect it via Ethernet? If the problem is Wi-Fi only, it could be that multicasts (which includes broadcasts, such as ARP requests) are not being delivered reliably on your Wi-Fi network. If your E3000 is set to use WPA2 "mixed mode" (where original WPA/TKIP is enabled alongside WPA2/AES-CCMP), see if switching to pure WPA2 (AES-CCMP only) resolves the problem.

Comment: That was the problem. If you want to put your comment as an answer i will +1and accept